# Word that refers to objects found in kitchens

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What refers to tools common to the kitchen? For example utensils, plates, bowls, cups, cutting boards etc. At first I thought "kitchen appliances" but usually the phrase refers to electronic devices exclusively.

EDIT: I should add that food should definitely not be included by the word's definition.

Comment: utensils might work by itself

Answer (score 6):

Maybe *kitchenware* is what you are looking for:

> Kitchenware includes utensils, appliances, dishes, cookware, and so on for use in the kitchen.
>
> [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitchenware)

> utensils and appliances for use in a kitchen
>
> [[Merriam-Webster]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kitchenware)

Comment: Ah, you were just a bit quicker :-)

Answer (score 5):

**[Kitchenware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitchenware)** covers everything you would want in a kitchen.

Answer (score 1):

Kitchen [supplies](http://www.realsimple.com/food-recipes/tools-products/kitchen-supplies-0) is a general term to refer to the whole set of things generally used in a kitchen.

Also *kitchen accessories*.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kitchen%20supplies%2Ckitchen%20accessories&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckitchen%20supplies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckitchen%20accessories%3B%2Cc0) kitchen supplies/kitchen accessories

Answer (score 1):

For the objects mentioned in the question **Kitchenware** would be more appropriate as
**Kitchenware** are the hardware utensils for use in a kitchen.