# A collective name for eating related items

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What would be a good word that includes and covers food-consumption related items such as plates, bowls, pots, pans and utensils?  Thanks you

Comment: See also [What’s the difference between “Kitchen gear” and “Kitchenware”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414757/what-s-the-difference-between-kitchen-gear-and-kitchenware)

Comment: You guys are beautiful

Comment: See also [Word that refers to objects found in kitchens](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209293/word-that-refers-to-objects-found-in-kitchens)